# Mutating JSON to work with react-jsonschema-form

Tags: javascript, json, object, react-jsonschema-forms

I am getting started with [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form), It requires input in a particular format. 
I am given a nested JSON but i am unable to recursively mutate the JSON according to the required input format.

Given is this JSON

```
{
  "Coordinates": {
    "X-Coordinate": 47,
    "Y-Coordinate": -122
  },
  "Coordination Type": {
    "Cartesion Mode": false,
    "Starting Range": {
      "Start": 8000,
      "End": 9000
    }
  },
  "Map": {
    "Offline Map": false,
    "URL": "http://localhost:9000"
  }
}
```

And this new JSON is needed to be generated recursively.

```
{
  "Coordinates": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Coordinates",
    "properties": {
      "X-Coordinate": {
        "type": "number",
        "title": "X-Coordinate",
        "default": 47
      },
      "Y-Coordinate": {
        "type": "number",
        "title": "Y-Coordinate",
        "default": -122
      }
    }
  },
  "Coordination Type": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Coordination Type",
    "properties": {
      "Cartesion Mode": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "title": "Cartesion Mode",
        "default": false
      },
      "Starting Range": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Start Range",
        "properties": {
          "Start": {
            "type": "number",
            "title": "Start",
            "default": 8000
          },
          "End": {
            "type": "number",
            "title": "End",
            "default": 9000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Map": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Map",
    "properties": {
      "Offline Map": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "title": "Offline Map",
        "default": false
      },
      "URL": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "URL",
        "default": "http://localhost:9000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to achieve this using iterative format but that is not scalable. And i have been stuck for hours to get this in recursive method.

I would really appreciate if i get a recursive method to update this given JSON to the required format in `javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this gets it done. Let me know if you see something I missed.

```js
// input data copied from question
const input = {
  "Coordinates": {
    "X-Coordinate": 47,
    "Y-Coordinate": -122
  },
  "Coordination Type": {
    "Cartesion Mode": false,
    "Starting Range": {
      "Start": 8000,
      "End": 9000
    }
  },
  "Map": {
    "Offline Map": false,
    "URL": "http://localhost:9000"
  }
};

// recursive field conversion function
const convertField = (key, value) => (
  {
    type: typeof value, // 'object', 'boolean', 'number', 'string'
    title: key, // field name is also the title (e.g. 'Starting Range')
    ...(
      typeof value !== 'object'
      ? { default: value } // primitive type. default and we're done
      : {  
        properties: Object.entries(value)
        .reduce((facc, [field, fvalue]) => ({
          ...facc, // keep previous iterations
          [field]: { // keep the field name, e.g. 'Starting Range',
          ...convertField(field, fvalue) // recurse for the field's value
        }
      }), {})
    }
    )
  }
  );
  
  // kick it off
  const output = Object.entries(input)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc, // retain previous iteration results
    [key]: {...convertField(key, value)} // convert each property
  }), {}
  );
  
  // show the results
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = (JSON.stringify(output, null, 2))
```

```html
<pre id="result" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) can be used to transform the values :

```js
var json = `{
  "Coordinates": {
    "X-Coordinate": 47,
    "Y-Coordinate": -122
  },
  "Coordination Type": {
    "Cartesion Mode": false,
    "Starting Range": {
      "Start": 8000,
      "End": 9000
    }
  },
  "Map": {
    "Offline Map": false,
    "URL": "http://localhost:9000"
  }
}`

var obj = JSON.parse(json, (key, val, type = typeof val) => !key ? val : 
  { type, title: key, [type === 'object' ? 'properties' : 'default']: val } )
  
console.log(obj)
```